# Issue with NSArray Address

Tags: ios, nsarray

I'm trying to print memory address of array but i'm getting same memory address for all three array
Let me explain more
I have taken three array

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arr3 = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

when i'm printing memory address

```
NSLog(@"arr1 = %p, arr2 = %p, arr3 = %p", arr1, arr2, arr3);
```

all memory address same

**Output:**

```
arr1 = 0x7f9c01d21550, arr2 = 0x7f9c01d21550, arr3 = 0x7f9c01d21550
```

but when i print memory address with this code

```
NSLog(@"arr1 = %p, arr2 = %p, arr3 = %p", &arr1, &arr2, &arr3);
```

Memory address is diffrent

**Output:**

```
arr1 = 0x7fff5fb8e338, arr2 = 0x7fff5fb8e330, arr3 = 0x7fff5fb8e328
```

I don't know why first NSLog print same address.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first NSLog printed the arrays. The second NSLog printed the addresses of the three variables where the arrays were stored. For the second NSLog you would have got the same result even if you never assigned an array.

The reason why the first NSLog prints the same address three times is that [[NSArray alloc] init] will *always* return an identical object. Call [[NSArray alloc] init] a billion times and only *one* NSArray object will ever be created. Since an NSArray is immutable, and you can never add anything to this empty array, why should the OS waste space to allocate more than one array? (This is actually a very useful optimisation if you have many empty arrays).

Comment: If you think my question is useful to others , vote up